# firefox,vs code, ubuntu software center stopped working suddenly

Tags: firefox, 22.04

Some apps have stopped working all of a sudden. I just ran sudo apt upgrade and update to update the system, and apps stopped working. Icons are still there but when I double click them nothing happens.
I also reinstalled them but to no use.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Run `firefox` in  a terminal and post the output

Answer (score 0):

I ran firefox in terminal, output was `/var/lib/snaps` has other permission `40777`.
I had made a mistake, I had given `/` permission `777`. When I changed back to `755`, everything went back to normal.